# PHP 7.2 warning for unquoted string in arrays inconsistency

Tags: php, arrays, migration, warnings, php-7.2

This gives the classical warning (that in next version will be an error):

```
$var[$otherVar[someIndex]] = $myValue;
```

This does not:

```
$var["$otherVar[someIndex]"] = $myValue;
```

Both works the same.

Shouldn't PHP 7.2 warn in both cases?

In case it does not, what is the justification to allow the second one, with the new rules PHP new versions tries to impose?

Comment: Not sure about the change, but: In the first example `someIndex` can reasonably be assumed to be a constant, in the second it is within double quotes so it cannot be interpreted as a constant.

Comment: Just as a clarification, this is not actually a new rule: that first example has *always* been wrong, it just gave a Notice which most people overlooked, rather than a Warning which gets people's attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation doesn't require that the key be quoted, because the key is *already a string*. It won't be interpreted as a constant (which is the point of the message you get from your first example), and there's no chance that you meant to get `$otherVar[someIndex()]`, because that wouldn't even work as intended in this context. So the problems with barewords simply don't apply.

You will get a message if you tried to say `$var["{$otherVar[someIndex]}"]`. Variables interpolated that way work more like you expect, and `someIndex` will again be interpreted as a constant.